# Fill missing/empty rows based on past or future values

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data

```
ID Price 
1  0
1  0
1  0
1  5
2  2
2  0
2  0
2  3
3  0
3  0
3  0
3  0
4  2
4  2
4  0
4  2
```

I want to fill in the values of missing cells based on past or future values in a certain ID but if all the values are zero for a particular ID leave it as it is.

So the table looks like

```
ID Price 
1  5
1  5
1  5
1  5
2  2
2  2
2  2
2  3
3  0
3  0
3  0
3  0
4  2
4  2
4  2
4  2
```

I tried solving it with following code

```
is.na(df$Price) <- df$Price==0
setDT(df1)[,Price := na.locf(na.locf(Price, na.rm=FALSE), fromLast=TRUE) , by = ID]
```

But it changes all the value of Price to either FALSE or TRUE. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When I run your code, the result looks as your expected result, except all Price entries for ID == 3 are NA. You can easily change that back to 0 if you wish

Comment: Same here. Seems that they just need to change the `NA` to `0` back.

Comment: just add `[is.na(Price), Price := 0]` and you should be fine

Comment: What do you fill the missing values with ID 2 by the value 2 (instead of 3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a variant of the OP's code to do all the steps within the data.table framework.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table'.  Convert the 'Price' values that are 0 to NA, use `na.locf` from the start and end values, grouped by 'ID', and finally convert the 'NA' values to 0.

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[,  PriceN := na.locf(na.locf(Price*(NA_real_^!Price),
     na.rm=FALSE), fromLast=TRUE, na.rm=FALSE), ID
       ][is.na(PriceN), PriceN := 0]
```

Comment: @docendodiscimus  Sorry, didn't check the OP's code, started coding with the data.  But, this should fix whatever the problem is in the OP's code.

Comment: Worked fine. Thanks@akrun